# Kerberos KDC has no support for encryption type while getting credentials

Tags: active-directory, encryption, kerberos

I am configuring an apache/SSO authentication with an AD with Kerberos.
My http server is a Debian Wheezy and the AD is a Windows Server 2012.

I generated keytabs files on WS2012 with `kpass` command for each encryption type available on WS2012.

When I try to open a session with a user `test@DOMAIN.COM` with `kinit`, it works.

When I try to open a session with my `HTTP/web.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM`, I get the message:

```
kvno HTTP/web.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
kvno: KDC has no support for encryption type while getting credentials for HTTP/web.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
```

Also, when I check encryption used for `test@DOMAIN.COM`, I have:

```
root@SERVER:~# klist -e
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: test@DOMAIN.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
03/04/2015 12:48:21  03/04/2015 22:48:17  krbtgt/DOMAIN.COM@DOMAIN.COM
        renew until 04/04/2015 12:48:21, Etype (skey, tkt): arcfour-hmac, arcfour-hmac
```

I tried to customize my `/etc/krb5.conf` with:

```
  default_tgs_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
  default_tkt_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
```

And by using the keytab file encrypted with `arcfour-hmac` without success.

I don't understand how to change encryption type used to communicate, why it always wants arcfour-hmac and why when I give it arcfour-hmac encryption, nothing change...

How to be sure that /etc/krb5.conf changes are effective and how to make the Kerberos ticket generation work too?

Comment: The KDC told you the error. What enc types does the service principal have?

Answer (score 9):

The encryption types supported by an Active Directory domain controller are listed in the `msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes` attribute of the domain controller's computer object. In a default installation, they are typically something like:

```
RC4_HMAC_MD5
AES128_CTS_HMAC_SHA1_96
AES256_CTS_HMAC_SHA1_96
```

This is a bitmask which works out to decimal 28, so it'd be something like `00011100`.

So when you ask why the domain controller "always wants only ARC4-HMAC," it is because your client doesn't have any of the other two encryption types in common with the domain controller, so they are eliminated during the negotiation process.

(Note: RC4_HMAC_MD5 is really the worst and weakest of all the possible encryption types here, but it is also sometimes necessary to support legacy scenarios and interoperability with non-Microsoft products.)

I looked up some documentation and found an example of someone else's configuration file and thought this might be useful:

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Kerberos

```
; for Windows 2008 with AES
   default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
   default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
   permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
```

Notice that, in addition to supporting better encryption types, they are also specifying `rc4-hmac` in their configuration, which is different from what you have, `arcfour-hmac-md5`. (Also don't forget the `permitted_enctypes` line, which I did not see in your post.)

I'm not 100% sure that will solve your issue, as I'm not in a position to test it right now, but hopefully it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

This is most generic problem while configuring kerberos, Please resolve this by doing the following,

1) `vi /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf`

2) check for `supported_enctypes` , use any encryption techniques mentioned in there.

Hope this resolves the problem.